# Navigation Type (Fixed Tabs + Swipe)

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabhost, swipe

In my application i have a tabhost with a tabwidget that have several Tabs.
Now i need a tab that show me inside the tabcontent a schedule grid that allow swipe to right and left to move through the months. But i need that the tab stay fixes and only the schedule swipes.

The navigation type (Fixed tabs + Swipe) allow me that? From what I understand this navigation allow the swipe but the tab don't stay the same.

What i need is possible?
Thanks for your help and attention.

Answer (score 1):

I would say possible, stay with your codes on tabhost and tabwidget.

So I would assume one of those tabs are calling an Activity which probably named Schedule.class, by default tabhost does not allow any swiping to change tab feature, that is fine.

So in your Schedule Activity, you would be using **ViewPager**, I learnt how to use it from this article: http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/android-page-swiping-using-viewpager/

Which is pretty easy to be understood. You may try to use it, hope I answered your question

**Update: Here's a sample**

Schedule.class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.schedule);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment1.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment2.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment3.class.getName()));

    MyFragmentAdapter miscFragmentAdapter = new MyFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

    viewPager.setAdapter(miscFragmentAdapter);
}
```

MyFragmentAdapter.class

```
public class MyFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public MiscFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }
}
```

schedule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment1.class or Fragment2.class or Fragment3.class

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            // We have different layouts, and in one of them this
            // fragment's containing frame doesn't exist.  The fragment
            // may still be created from its saved state, but there is
            // no reason to try to create its view hierarchy because it
            // won't be displayed.  Note this is not needed -- we could
            // just run the code below, where we would create and return
            // the view hierarchy; it would just never be used.
            return null;
        }
        return (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
    }
}
```

fragment1 is a simple layout with whatever you want inside it.

Comment: Hello Chor. Thanks for your reply. On of tabs calls a Schedule.class(FragmentActivity) and this FragmentActivity is responsible for swipe. But is possible put a fragmentActivity inside a fragmentLayout responsible by the tabcontent of each tab? Thanks

Comment: I do not really understand your point on fragmentLayout, are you using any in your project? But as far as I understand, it shouldn't matter what parent layout you use. You may try start the test by implementing codes above into your project, and see how it results.